# Split file from a streaming output with custom name and gzip

Tags: shell, gzip, split

I have a script with a while loop that will print a text. I want to save it into files with custom name.

#### Script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
done
```

I can run split:

```bsh
./loopscript.sh  | split -dl 10000 --additional-suffix=.txt
```

#### Output:

```
x001.txt
x002.txt
x003.txt
x004.txt
x005.txt
```

But I want to save it like below:

```
myoutput.001.gz
myoutput.002.gz
myoutput.003.gz
myoutput.004.gz
myoutput.005.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the custom name (the prefix) you can just add it at the end as argument. For filtering all output files through `gzip` you can use the `--filter=COMMAND` option. Also `-a3` is optional if you need to define the suffix length to 3 characters (`001`, `002` etc) . Also note the `-` (to read stdin) before the output prefix argument.

```bsh
./loopscript.sh | split -a3 -dl 10000 --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' - myoutput.
```

will produce gzipped files (of 10K lines if unzipped) named like:

```
myoutput.000.gz
myoutput.001.gz
myoutput.002.gz
```

---

From `man split` the syntax says (optional) output prefix goes to the end:

```
SYNOPSIS
       split [OPTION]... [FILE [PREFIX]]
```

and `--filter` accepts `$FILE` as the filename out of the `split` command:

```
       --filter=COMMAND
              write to shell COMMAND; file name is $FILE
```